# Using RSA in Python 3, need to sign a message (without hashing the message)

Tags: python, rsa, digital-signature

Python 3 lib I am using:[RSA stuvel](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/usage.html)

In this library the sign function first generates a hash and then signs it. Any way I can get it to sign a message without hashing it first?

Alternatively any other library available which can do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function [here: `Package Crypto :: Package PublicKey :: Module RSA :: Class _RSAobj sign`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#sign).

But note that usually the signature generation is over a hash, extended by an DER encoded structure indicating the hash, which is in turn padded and turned into a number to form the input to the actual modular exponentiation operation. This method just performs the last step; you'd have to do the other ones yourself, and note that they are *required* from a security perspective.

This is all specified in the [PKCS#1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017) specifications. Note that this is tricky stuff, you may want to copy it from an open source implementation. Or you could just provide it a hash, which is a very good idea - to hash the message first.

There is also the retracted ISO/IEC 9796 which describes signatures with message recovery, which is what you may be after. I don't see an implementation in Python directly. Be sure what you are doing before using a library even if you find it though.

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, took some time for me to find it as well.